# setText crashes with custom font

Tags: android, fonts

I have set up a custom font in the assets folder /assets/fonts/7led.ttf and initialized font for a text view.

```
// LED font used in Dimmer display
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/7led.ttf");  
TextView tv  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DimmerView);    
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Int the xml files I set text to default "100"

```
          <TextView
    android:id="@+id/DimmerView"
    android:layout_width="169dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="700dp"
    android:background="@color/text_color"
    android:text="100"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/background_color"
    android:textSize="100dp" />
```

The font displays correctly but when I try to change the text it crashes.

```
    TextView.setText("101");
```

I have read the many answers to this topic but still cannot resolve the crash. one of the many error I see is exiting with uncaught exception.

logcat
09-09 14:05:47.851: W/dalvikvm(3729): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414422a0)

I have resolved the crash.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/digital_counter_7.ttf");  
final TextView tv  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DimmerView);      // for display the received data from the Arduino

tv.setText("101"); 
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

This line can change the text

```
                tv.setText("102");
```

Comment: Why are you setting text to 'TextView' when your textview is 'tv' ?

Comment: How would you suggest setting the textview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have made just a little mistake calling the folder:

if you have put your .ttf file on /assets/folder/7led.ttf, you need to call

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "folder/7led.ttf");
```

and not

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/7led.ttf");
```

Comment: The folder is called fonts, this was my typo  /assets/fonts/7led.ttf

Answer (score 0):

My error was simply a typo, "tff" instead of "ttf". Check that too just in case to save yourself a headache.